# function for checking if a char array contains only allowed chars

Tags: c++

how do I change/remove this awful "if".The function is checking if a char array "equation" contains only the numbers from 0 to 9 and the symbols in the "if".

```
bool containsOnlyAllowedSymbols(const char* equation)
{
    bool a;
    while (*equation) {
        if ((*equation < 48 || *equation > 57) && *equation != '+' && *equation != '-' && *equation != '*' && *equation != '/' && *equation != '(' && *equation != ')' && *equation != '[' && *equation != ']' && *equation != '{' && *equation != '}') {
            return false;
        }
        else
            a = true;
        equation++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: For a start, move that expression into a function, and use `std::isdigit` for the numerical bit.

Comment: If the function works correctly, I recommend coming to [CodeReview.se]. It would be nice to include a test `main()` in the post there.

Comment: Where did the string come from? It could be easier to check each character as the text comes in, rather than all at once afterwords.

Comment: it comes from cin.getline(equation,100); Also we are learning functions and I was told to do it that way

Comment: It’s C++, use std::string.

Comment: @PeteBecker, were you thinking about `std::istream_iterator<char>` and `std::all_of`?

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't guarantee the character set that will be used.

Comment: Load the allowed characters as keys of an unordered_map. Then query each candidate character. If a char is not in the unordered_map, then an un-allowed character is present, and process accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be tempted to use good old [std::strspn](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strspn) like this:

```
bool containsOnlyAllowedSymbols(const char* equation)
{
    return std::strspn(equation, "0123456789+-*/()[]{}") == std::strlen(equation);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, there's also `std::string::find_first_not_of`. Same idea there.

Comment: @chris, shouldn't `std::all_of` short circuit and be the same  but clearer version of `std::string::find_first_not_of`? standard doesn't mandate that, but probably any sane implementation does that.

Comment: @chris I would have used that if it were strings (It should be). Unfortunally the more generic `std::find_...()` functions do not include `...first_not_of()`.

Comment: @Incomputable, Yes, `all_of` would be my preference for how to spell it. Not sure what the "naive" performance difference between the two methods comes out to, but it probably doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @chris, I just wanted to say that standard doesn't guarantee stopping on the first unfit element of the range. So it might run until the end even if the first element is unfit already.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using std::regex_match:

```
std::regex pattrn("[0-9*/+-]+");
bool only_legal_equation_chars(char const * equation)
{
  return std::regex_match(equation, equation+strlen(equation), pattern);
}
```

Comment: Might want to include the required header too.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) fits quite nicely here:

```
std::string mystr{"123+-*["};
auto is_allowed_character = [](unsigned char x) //related to C
                            {
                                return (x >= 48 && x <= 57) ||
                                        x == '+' ||
                                        //so on
                                        ;
                            }
return std::all_of(mystr.begin(), mystr.end(), 
                   is_allowed_character);
```

I removes the `if`, the loop, and makes it more idiomatic C++. Also the thing can work on any iterator, even one made from `std::cin`.

Answer (score 0):

Another `regex` solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

bool containsOnlyAllowedSymbols(char const *equation)
{
    std::regex re(R"([^0-9(){}[\]*+-/])");
    return !std::regex_search(equation, re);
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << containsOnlyAllowedSymbols("(10+20)-200*4") << std::endl;
    std::cout << containsOnlyAllowedSymbols("10+20-{200}abc") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/wR0yA0

Add space to regex pattern if expression can contain spaces.

Comment: Raw string literals and taking advantage of special characters losing their meaning inside character classes can make it easier to digest: `R"([^0-9(){}[\]*+-/])"`. Debatable whether the raw literal even helps at that point.

Comment: @chris good point, if anything it makes it more readable, thanks!